how to transfer from a text variable a small piece of text
with the following code, I set a variable \AcIII with the bla bla text.
I would extract a part of variable (i.e. the first two bla bla) and store it on another variable (that I use next).
Can I obtain that? If yes, how?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\newcommand{\AcIII}{bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla}
\begin{document}

\AcIII

\end{document}

thank you
Renato

no, plain text. No macro. it is text  stored on a DB, I copy it and paste on a .tex file

EDITED to meet OP comment to support substring extraction into separate macro.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand{\AcIII}{bla bla blax blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla}

\newtoks\mytoks
\newcommand\addtotoks[1]{\global\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtotoks[1]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter{#1}}

\def\getwords#1[#2]-[#3]{%
  \foreachitem\z\in#1[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt>\numexpr#2-1\relax
      \ifnum\zcnt<\numexpr#3+1\relax
        \xaddtotoks{\z}%
        \addtotoks{ }%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\somewords\expandafter{\the\mytoks}%
}
\begin{document}

\AcIII

\setsepchar{ }%Use space separator to parse list
\readlist\mybla{\AcIII}

There are a total of \listlen\mybla[] words in list.

The 3rd word is \mybla[3].

To extract words from location 4-9, we could do this:

\getwords\mybla[4]-[9]
\somewords

\end{document}



can I put the result (from 4 to 9) into a variable? and I compile with pdfLatex is it ok?

@RenatoP Please see my EDIT.  I have defined a substring-extraction macro.

In this implementation, the variables have names (without a backslash), that avoids inventing command names.
The text is stored in a sequence, splitting it at spaces.
We can then use the sequence, by printing it restoring spaces or inserting a different separator (in the second examples a hyphen).
Extraction can be from any item to any other. The starting point is, by default, 1. We can specify going to the last item by specifying -1 as the mandatory argument. So we don't even need to count the items and do arithmetic. For example,
\extractfromtextvariable{uptothelastbutone}{AcIII}{-2}

would just exclude the last item. See the code below for other examples.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definetextvariable}{mm}
 {% #1 = new variable, #2 = text
  \renatop_textvar_define:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\usetextvariable}{m +O{~}}
 {% #1 = variable, #2 = text to put in between items (default a space)
  \renatop_textvar_use:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\extracttextvariable}{mmO{1}m}
 {% #1 = new variable, #2 = old variable, #3 = start, #4 = end
  \renatop_textvar_extract:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\lengthoftextvariable}{m}
 {
  \seq_count:c { l_renatop_textvar_#1_seq }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__renatop_textvar_temp_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \renatop_textvar_define:nn
 {
  % allocate a sequence
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_renatop_textvar_#1_seq }
  % set the sequence by splitting at spaces
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_renatop_textvar_#1_seq } {~} { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \renatop_textvar_use:nn
 {
  % use the sequence with the desired separator
  \seq_use:cn { l_renatop_textvar_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \renatop_textvar_extract:nnnn
 {
  % clear a temporary tl variable
  \tl_clear:N \l__renatop_textvar_temp_tl
  % add to the tl variable the items braced
  \seq_map_inline:cn { l_renatop_textvar_#2_seq }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__renatop_textvar_temp_tl { {##1} }
   }
  % extract the desired items
  \tl_set:Ne \l__renatop_textvar_temp_tl
   {
    \tl_range:Nnn \l__renatop_textvar_temp_tl { #3 } { #4 }
   }
  % allocate a new sequence
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_renatop_textvar_#1_seq }
  % add the extracted items
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__renatop_textvar_temp_tl
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_renatop_textvar_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definetextvariable{AcIII}{aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj kk ll}

\begin{document}

\usetextvariable{AcIII}

\usetextvariable{AcIII}[-]

The variable \texttt{AcIII} has \lengthoftextvariable{AcIII} items.

\extracttextvariable{firstthree}{AcIII}{3}
\usetextvariable{firstthree} (first three)

\extracttextvariable{fromtwotosix}{AcIII}[2]{6}
\usetextvariable{fromtwotosix} (from second to sixth)

\extracttextvariable{fromtwotolast}{AcIII}[2]{-1}
\usetextvariable{fromtwotolast} (from second to last)

\extracttextvariable{lastthree}{AcIII}[-3]{-1}
\usetextvariable{lastthree} (last three)

\end{document}


One could think to add merging variables or adding items to existing ones (at the end or at the beginning).
